# Send packet to webserver?

Tags: python, packets

I'm just getting into python, and I dont now how to send packets.
So can anyone tell me how can I send packets to a webserver? I would also like to choose the size of the packet myself?

I'm using python 2.7.

Comment: Packets of what? You want to do http requests "bare metal" style? Any reason you need/want to go such low level and not just use standard http libraries?

Comment: [Python `socket` module](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html), but what are you trying to do?

Comment: What sort of packet are you trying to send?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) module, to easily create http requests. Or, if you want to take a bare approach, you can use the [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) module to manually create a TCP connection and send whatever packets you would like.

Answer (score 0):

```
from httplib import HTTPConnection
...
HTTPConnection.putheader("Content-Length","512")
HTTPConnection.endheaders()
HTTPConnection.send(data)
```

multipart/form-data example:
http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/cgi.shtml#upload  upload_test.py